# Why is my type defined structure not visible in another header? - C

Tags: c, struct, visibility

In my application I have a structure called LED_strip. I need this structure to be visible in other source files, so I typedef'd it in one of my header files, and then declared it as extern below in the same file.

In the source file directly associated with this header, I defined the actual structure. Now, in another source file, I included the mentioned header. In this file I defined a function which takes the external structure as an argument.

The problem is, the compiler throws an error in my second header file, in the declaration of the abovementioned function - it says there is no such type. What am I doing wrong?

#### `CV_test.h`

```
typedef struct {
    char * name;
    int voltage;
    int nominal_current;
    int psu_current;
    int power;
    int current_limit;
    int cal_value;
    uint8_t wait_tim;
    uint8_t cal_flag;
    uint8_t valid_flag;
    uint8_t difference;
} LED_strip;


extern LED_strip test_struct_container;
```

#### `CV_test.c`

```
#include "CV_test.h"

LED_strip test_struct_container;
```

Here I include the header, and define a structure of a LED_strip type.

#### `commands.c`

```
#include "CV_test.h"
#include "commands.h"

void cmd_get_struct(const char * buf, LED_strip *LED)
{
    sscanf(buf,"%s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", LED->name, &LED->nominal_current, &LED->voltage,
    &LED->psu_current, &LED->power, &LED->current_limit, &LED->wait_tim, &LED->difference);
}
```

Now this is my function; it takes a pointer to my structure as an argument; at this point, there are no errors indicated.

#### commands.h - this is the line I get my error at:

```
void cmd_get_struct(const char *, LED_strip *);
```

```
error: unknown type name 'LED_strip'
```

This is the actual error message. Quite honestly I am out of ideas.  To me, everything seems to be done correctly, yet I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: `commands.c` needs to include the header file.

Comment: That last line is a function prototype, is it supposed to be in a header file `commands.h`?

Comment: That header file needs to have `#include "CV_test.h"` as well.

Comment: Please verify that I've got the code labelled correctly with headings (file names) before the code in that file.  Then explain where the code in `commands.c` is compiling OK and not — there isn't a simple way to make `LED_strip` into an unknown type after the first section of the code has compiled OK.  If `void cmd_get_struct(const char *, LED_strip *);` is in a header `commands.h`, then that header should `#include "CV_test.h"` to get the declaration of the type.  Since your structure has no tag (you didn't write `typedef struct LED_strip { … } LED_strip;`) you don't have many alternatives.

Comment: You can get these kind of strange errors if you don't use header guards. If you fail to provide `#ifndef CV_TEST_H #define CV_TEST_H ... #endif` in your header, and then include that header from multiple files, then each file (translation unit) might end up creating its own version of the struct.

Comment: A few things: commands.c also has CV_test included, i forgot to paste it. Commands.c is compiling correctly. Also, Eclipse always adds header guards in my header files.